# TypeError: (0 , import_vite_plugin_html.vitePluginHtml) is not a function in Vite.config.js

Tags: javascript, node.js, vue.js, terminal, vite

even ChatGPT hasn't been able to solve this problem since 2 days giving me same loop of solutions which are not working at all. My terminal output should be enough... Please someone help, I've upgraded/downgraded, fixed imports, reset .js files, nothing has worked. Why does my Vite dev server fail to start due to TypeError? How can I fix a TypeError in Vite.config.js and start my dev server?

```
PS D:\*****\*******\*******\raone\my-vite-app> npm run dev 

> personal-assistant@0.0.0 dev
> vite


 ERROR  failed to load config from D:\*******\******\********\******\my-vite-app\vite.config.js


 ERROR  error when starting dev server:                                      19:45:56  
TypeError: (0 , import_vite_plugin_html.vitePluginHtml) is not a function
    at Object.<anonymous> (D:\******\*****\******\******\my-vite-app\vite.config.js:37:48)
    at Module._compile (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1254:14)
    at require.extensions.<computed> [as .js] (D:\******\******\******\******\my-vite-app\node_modules\vite\dist\node\chunks\dep-6e2fe41e.js:62006:20)
    at Module.load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1117:32)
    at Module._load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:958:12)
    at Module.require (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1141:19)
    at require (node:internal/modules/cjs/helpers:110:18)
    at loadConfigFromBundledFile (D:\******\******\*******\*****\my-vite-app\node_modules\vite\dist\node\chunks\dep-6e2fe41e.js:62014:17)
    at loadConfigFromFile (D:\******\*******\********\*****\my-vite-app\node_modules\vite\dist\node\chunks\dep-6e2fe41e.js:61933:32)
    at process.processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:95:5)

PS D:\*******\********\*******\*****\my-vite-app>
```

I was expecting it to open up in browser, but the terminal encounters the error starting server

Comment: Please share your package.json, tsconfig and vite.config.ts

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: Goga asked codes -

Comment: pacakge.json - {
  "name": "personal-assistant",
  "private": true,
  "version": "0.0.0",
  "scripts": {
    "dev": "vite",
    "build": "vite build",
    "preview": "vite preview"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "autoprefixer": "^10.4.7",
    "postcss": "^8.4.14",
    "tailwindcss": "^3.3.2",
    "vite": "^2.6.14",
    "vue": "^3.2.25"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@vitejs/plugin-vue": "^2.3.4",
    "vite-plugin-html": "^3.2.0"
  }
}

Comment: vite.config.js - import { defineConfig } from 'vite';
import vue from '@vitejs/plugin-vue';
import { vitePluginHtml } from 'vite-plugin-html';

export default defineConfig({
  plugins: [
    vue(),
    vitePluginHtml({
      template: './index.html'
    })
  ]
});

Comment: there is no tsconfig

Comment: @Goga respond pls

Comment: As it is hard to identify the problem, I suggest you create a github repo or share your project otherwise. Ideally, it is only that which causes your error, so a minimal example of your project which still causes the error. This has two benefits: 1. in the process of minimizing your project, you might find the cause yourself and 2. others looking at it can replicate it easily

Comment: so i make github and give u link? It's a stupid program anyways...